# IIS rewrites and handlers conflict

Tags: django, iis, url-rewriting, wfastcgi

I'm trying to set up a Django/Angular application under IIS.

When I set a similar application under nginx, I pass all URLs starting with `/api` (my backend) or `/admin` (the Django admin interface) to Django. I also set two locations: `/` and `/static` - both are aliases to the folder with all the static resources.

I need to alias `/static`, too, because Django's admin application references resources at `/static/admin/...`

I can't get IIS to work the same way. I'm using `wfastcgi` to interface with Django, and a rewrite rule to map `/static` back to `/`. This is the relevant portion of my `Web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Static Perfix" stopProcessing="true" >
            <match url="^static/(.+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
<handlers>
    <add name="Admin" 
         path="/admin" 
         verb="*" 
         modules="FastCgiModule" 
         scriptProcessor="..." 
         resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

This doesn't work. When I access `/admin` the handler catches it and forwards the request to Django, as it should. Django return an html page with resources located at `/static/admin/base.css` (for example).

When the browser tries to load such a resource the rewrite rule catches it, rewrites it to `/admin/base.css`, and then the handler catches it and forwards it to Django, which doesn't know what `/admin/base.css` is and returns a 404.

I tried making `/static` a Virtual Directory pointing to the same physical directory as the root directory. This caused all sorts of conflicts because my root `Web.config` was read twice, causing all sorts of duplicate key violations (for all the keys I have defined, more or less).

I would appreciate any help on getting out of this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up avoiding the problem altogether, by restructuring my static resources folder and adding an actual `static` subfolder that contains the Admin static files.

I will no longer be able to use `manage.py collectstatic` for front-end deployment, though, I will need to create an additional script. Oh well.